# Intent.action.VIEW does not work on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I need to open my application when clicked the URL Link in E-mail, Message or Browser applications. So, see the my code for this feature:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mysite.org"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This code is sufficient and works on some mobile devices, especially devices with android versions **5.0, 6.0 and 7.0** but does not work on versions **7.1 and 8.0**. Why does this happen? Is it a permission problem?

Comment: How does your `Intent` look like?

Comment: @MuratK. I need to open my app when the user clicked a link (mysite.org) from gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ex: Your url will be something like **https://example.com** and you have the intent filter in Android Manifest as below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.droid.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Use the **URL Mapping** editor to easily add URL intent filters to your Activities with Android App Links (Android Studio > Tools > Android App Links).

Answer (score 1):

After reading [changes in Android O](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html) I came to the conclusion that the problem is described as follows

> URIs cannot contain empty labels. Previously, the platform supported a
>   workaround to accept empty labels in host names, which is an illegal
>   use of URIs. This workaround was for compatibility with older libcore
>   releases. Developers using the API incorrectly would see an ADB
>   message: "URI example..com has empty labels in the hostname. This is
>   malformed and will not be accepted in future Android releases."
>   Android 8.0 removes this workaround; the system returns null for
>   malformed URIs.

So try adding `android:label="string resource"` to your `intent-filter`  syntax so  the user will see it in the alternatives menu.

Comment: So thr case WAS actually the missing label! Just for people to know if they look for it in future