# Why does intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) return null even though there is Activity to handle it?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm following the [Android Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-training/), specifically I'm working on [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-activity-with-implicit-intent/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#3) Codelab with implicit intents.

The Codelab has the following method:

```
public void openWebsite(View view) {
   String url = mWebsiteEditText.getText().toString();

   Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);

   if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(intent);
   } else {
       Log.d("ImplicitIntents", "Can't handle this intent!");
   }
}
```

The problem is that the `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` returns null, but if I omit this and just call the `startActivity(intent)`, it works fine and opens the Uri in Google Chrome.

I'm wondering why `intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())` returns null, even thought the Uri can be opened in Google Chrome?

The **Manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.implicitintents">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In this case the URL that we want to open comes from `EditText` field, so we can't use an `intent-filter` with `android:host` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47647713/7248094).

Comment: If you are testing on Android 11 or higher, you are being affected by [package visibility restrictions](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility).

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right. I tested it in the previous version and it works. I'm searching how can this be solved in Android 11.

Answer (score 7):

In case you haven't solve the problem yet.
I don't know if you are using API level 30, but if you are you should check this [new Package visibility  restrictions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility). Package Visibility has changed and apps are no longer able to access the Package Manager directly. You need to add a  element in your AndroidManifest file. In your case you would need something like this.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding a request to use the browser in the manifest. Now my manifest file looks like this. Try reading this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.quakereport">
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".EarthquakeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of problem for me:

1. Use queries into Android Manifest

   ```
    <queries>
    <!-- WebView -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>

    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>

    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    </intent>
   ```

2. Remove

   ```
    File sd_directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return File.createTempFile(new_name, ".jpg", sd_directory);
   ```

and use

```
      File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
      return new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".jpg");
```